# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int getal1 = random.Next(0, 100);

    Random random2 = new Random();
    int getal2 = random2.Next(0, 100);
    int Antwoord = getal1 + getal2;

    if (Antwoord == textBox1.Text);
        ...
}
```

it says

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

can someone help me?

Comment: You need to learn the basics of C#. The answer will be clear from even simple tutorials.

Comment: `Antwoord` is an integer, whereas `textBox1.Text` is a string. Thus you can't compare them. You have to cast `textBox1.Text` to integer before (or vice versa cast `Antwoord` to string).

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Antwoord.ToString() == textBox1.Text);
```

Write it like this. You want to check int to string, this can't happen. You should convert the int value to string or the string value to int. I advice you to convert int to string in other case you can have an exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an integer value, entered in the `TextBox`, you should try to parse its `Text`:

```
int textBox1Value;
if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out textBox1Value))
{
    // Here the text was successfully parsed to the textBox1Value variable
    if (Antwoord == textBox1Value)
    {
       ... // do your stuff
    }
}
```